# cout resolution in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iostream, cout

I created a c++ Win32 console application in VS2010, and in a separated class I have.

```
void Thing::display(){
    Point pt(0, 0);
    for( ; pt.y < m; pt.y++){
        for( ; pt.x < m; pt.x++){
            if (pt == pi){
                std::cout << "[  ]";
            }else {
                std::cout << "[" << Array[pt.x][pt.y] << "]";
                if ( pt.x == m ){
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which exists in the Thing class which is split between an h, and a cpp. point is an (x, y) point, and Array is a 2D array of ints, and pi is a private member for current location tracking.it keeps throwing errors of

```
error C2039: 'cout' : is not a member of 'std'
error C2065: 'cout' " undeclared identifier
```

and it does the same thing for endl. I can go into my _tmain() and write

```
cout << "Hello world" << endl
```

with no problem. when I attempt to tell the compiler for this file

```
using namespace std;
```

it throws inteslliSense: name must be a namespace name

Edit: suggestion of putting #include  into the header file caused

```
error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. did you gorget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?
```

moving the #inlcude  to stdafx.h causes same.

Edit2 (resolved):

placed

```
#include <iostream>
```

into stdafx.h, and then listed header files for the program. and listed

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

at the beginning of the .cpp files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you included iostream

```
#include <iostream>
```

in your header file?

Comment: when I try to put that in my header file it throws C1010

Comment: if you are using pre-compiled headers you need to #inlclude "stdafx.h" as the first line in all your cpp files.

Answer (score 2):

You likely did not include `<iostream>`.

Comment: I have that in my main, and when I try to put it in the header of the class it thows "C1010"

Comment: @gardian06: Put this in the `.cpp` file implementing the class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `<iostream>`.

The second problem you list is answered by the very error message itself:

> error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?

If you use precompiled headers, you need to include stdafx.h in your .cpp files. You probably forgot to do this, so the error tells you "Hey, I'm looking for this particular header, but I'm at the end of the file and still have not found it".

Comment: I have that in my main, and when I try to put it in the header of the class it thows "C1010"

Comment: For that particular error, see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7fz9ckx(v=vs.100).aspx). The errors you list above are due to not including iostream in the right place.